# Taking Visible range after AutoFilter

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to select filtered rows into a range variable `xRange`. I need to have some operations on that range. Before filtering there was 10000+ rows. After filtering it is 5000 rows. So after filtering I tried this to get the filtered range which is not working as I expected.

```
With Sheets("FullInvoice").Range("A1:N" & lRow)
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & fD, Criteria2:="<=" & lD

End With
Set xRange = Sheets("FullInvoice").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

I added a break point at Set xRange line. and tried xRange.rows.count. But its just returning 1 even there is 5000 rows. So whats my purpose is to take the cell value of first cell after filtering. How can I accomplish that.

When I try

```
dim s as string
s=xRange.Range("A1").value
```

It returning first cell value of the whole rows. Not from the filtered rows.

So how to solve this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
    With Sheets("FullInvoice").Range("A1:N" & lrow)
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & fd, Criteria2:="<=" & ld
End With

With Sheets("FullInvoice").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set xRange = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With
MsgBox xRange.Address

Dim s As String
s = xRange.Range("A1").Value
MsgBox s
```

Answer (score 2):

It's even easier than that. Just bring `xrange` inside your `With`. Also I'd use `Range.Cells(x,y)` rather than `Range.Range` to get a cell inside a range:

```
With Sheets("FullInvoice").Range("A1:N" & lRow)
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & fD, Criteria2:="<=" & lD
    Set xrange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With

MsgBox xrange.Cells(1, 1)
```